# SOAP Client request with Grails

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, groovy

I try to create a payment system with SOAP for ipayment (Germany) and in its documentation it is described that with the following SOAP request I might get the response shown in second code example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
  <capture> 
    <accountData> 
     <accountId>99999</accountId> 
     <trxuserId>99999</trxuserId> 
     <trxpassword>0</trxpassword> 
     <adminactionpassword> 
       5cfgRT34xsdedtFLdfHxj7tfwx24fe</adminactionpassword> 
    </accountData> 
    <origTrxNumber>1-25949395</origTrxNumber> 
    <transactionData> 
     <trxAmount>119</trxAmount> 
     <trxCurrency>EUR</trxCurrency> 
    </transactionData> 
  </capture> 
 </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And example response from server is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
  <ns1:captureResponse 
    xmlns:ns1="https://ipayment.de/service_v3/binding"> 
    <ipaymentReturn> 
     <status>SUCCESS</status> 
     <successDetails> 
      <retTransDate>25.07.08</retTransDate> 
      <retTransTime>17:08:08</retTransTime> 
      <retTrxNumber>1-25949407</retTrxNumber> 
      <retAuthCode></retAuthCode> 
     </successDetails> 
     <addressData> 
      <addrStreet>Ernst-Frey-Str. 9</addrStreet> 
      <addrCity>Karlsruhe</addrCity> 
      <addrZip>76135</addrZip> 
      <addrCountry>DE</addrCountry> 
     </addressData> 
     <addresscheckResult>UNCHECKED</addresscheckResult> 
     <paymentMethod>VisaCard</paymentMethod> 
     <trxPaymentDataCountry>US</trxPaymentDataCountry> 
    </ipaymentReturn> 
  </ns1:captureResponse> 
 </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I have no idea how to create the request as shown with grails. I try to use Spring WS plugin but the sample codes in documentation doesn't help at all. Do you know any source for some examples or any idea? WSDL schema can be found at https://ipayment.de/service/3.0/?wsdl
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If cookies are not needed for authentication to the WS (and they shouldn't :-) ), [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) is a nice library to use to create SOAP request.

Another method is to use [HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/index.html) which allows you to create tour exact requests and handle cookies if needed (You can do that with wslite, but with a bit more work)

Answer (score 0):

If you are scripting, a tip could be to use curl (if you have that available) directly from groovy. It's pretty powerful, easy to handle and you can do it in a one-liner.

Eg:
"curl -d \"${payload}\" -H \"Content-Type: text/xml\" ${wsUrl}".execute.text
Where the payload is the request(including the soap-envelope).